# How can i give a depth to an object created from graphics?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I am drawing some lines in my program using
graphics.lineTo(xx, yy);

The program has a background image over which these lines are drawn.
The problem which I am facing is that the image overshadows the lines and the lines are not visible to the user.

Since these lines do not have an id, I am not sure as to how I can assign a depth to them?

Any input/suggestions will help?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your code in particular but I'll try to point a direction. The best way for that is to place components in your application with particular orger like the following:

```
<s:Group>
    <s:BitmapImage />
    <MyCustomComponent />
</s:Group>
```

Where `MyCustomComponent` is something like the following:

```
public class MyCustomComponent extends UIComponent
{
    override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
    {
        super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
        // Your drawings here: graphics.lineTo(xx, yy);
    }
}
```

So now your drawings will be on a higher level than image.

Answer (score 0):

The z-index is set in the display list
If you want to bring something to the top of the display list just addChild again
For example

```
// this will place the BG on top of the myLinesSprite object
var container:Sprite = new Sprite( );
container.addChild( myLinesSprite );
container.addChild( myBGimage );

// now do another addchild
var container:Sprite = new Sprite( );
container.addChild( myLinesSprite );
container.addChild( myBGimage );
container.addChild( myLinesSprite ); // updates displayList does not add twice


// of course if you build it correctly the first time you wont have a worry
var container:Sprite = new Sprite( );
container.addChild( myBGimage );
container.addChild( myLinesSprite );
```